# Is there a way to declare a skin inline?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, mxml

Is there a way to declare a skin inline in a Flex 4 MXML Component? If not inline in the component then in the declarations or library tag? Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can in the declarations tag:

```
<s:Application>

<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Component className="testSkin">
        <s:Skin>
            <s:Rect width="100%" height="100%">
                <s:fill>
                     <s:SolidColor/>
                </s:fill>
            </s:Rect>
            <s:Group id="contentGroup"/>
        </s:Skin>
    </fx:Component>  
</fx:Declarations>

<s:SkinnableContainer skinClass="{Class(testSkin)}"/>

</s:Application>
```

The above code is merely guidance, don't expect it to compile.

In my tests, there is no performance penalty to using inline skins.

Answer (score 2):

Use the skinClass style.

In MXML, like this:

```
<s:List skinClass="com.myCustomSkins.MyCustomListSkin" />
```

In ActionScript, do something like this:

```
 myListClass.setStyle('skinClass',com.myCustomSkins.MyCustomListSkin);
```

In CSS, do something like this:

```
myListClass{
 skinClass : ClassReference(com.myCustomSkins.MyCustomListSkin);
}
```

I'm not sure what a library tag is that you refer to in your question.  This code is from memory, so my syntax may be a bit off.

Comment: That's not what I mean. I want to declare the skin class inline like you can declare a component inline so something like: <Button><skinClass><component><ButtonSkin>...</ButtonSkin></component></skinClass></Button>

Comment: Oh, I understand.  You don't want to reference another component, you want to create the skin on the fly?  I doubt that's possible.  You can only declare components in-line in very specific situations.  Did you try it?  What problems did you have?

Comment: The skinClass style only accepts Class references, and <fx:Component/> produces an IFactory, so they won't be compatible.